# How to get likes/dislikes from database using ternary operator in laravel php

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to retrieve the number of `likes` and `dislikes` a post have.

I've the following table in database, in which I've `like` column which decides like or dislike. if it is `1` it means `like` if it is `zero` it means `dislike`.

[image: table]

**Problem** :

I'm trying to `count` the number of `like(s)` a post has and then show it for each post, I'm trying to achieve this using ternary operator but I'm getting `1` like and `1` dislike for every post which is wrong according to the above table data.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong, because I think the code should work .

Because for `post_id` `1` the number of likes should be `2` according to the table , but I get `1` like and `1` dislike for each post.

**Code**
This is the code I'm trying to get the number of `likes` and `dislikes`

```
@if(count( $post->likes()->where('$post->like'==1) )>=1  )

   <small>{{ count($post->likes()->where('$post->like' ==1))>=1?count($post->likes()->where($post->like ==1)). ' Likes':count($post->likes()->where($post->like ==1)).'Dislike' }}</small>
   @else
                            <small>// similary do this for dislikes when like column in the above table is 0</small>

  @endif

                </small>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the count and withCount method from eloquent to make this easier for you

You can count the likes and dislikes in your controller like this:

```php
$posts = App\Post::withCount([
    'likes' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('like', 1);
    },
   'likes as dislikes_count' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('like', 0);
    }
])->get();
```

Then you can those counts this in your blade like

```html
Likes count: {{ $post->likes_count }}
Dislikes count: {{ $post->dislikes_count }}
```

Comment: thank you . this answer save my day. i dont know why this worked for me? $count = $this['smsList']->count(); ans smsList is my relation name.